# removing one character from a string

Tags: php

Given the address: 12345 West Palm Rd., #7B Daytona, FL

I am trying to remove the '.' character from 'Rd.' and the '#' character from '#7B'. However, I would like for these characters to be removed no matter what string is given...

Is there an easy way to do this?

I am familiar with strstr but it seems like a complicated way to do what I am trying to do...

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Do you want to remove all occurrences of `#` and `.` or only from special places?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str_replace (array(".", "#"), "", $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a convient string replace method for what you are trying to do.

```
$address = "12345 West Palm Rd., #7B Daytona, FL";
$characters = array('.','#',etc.);
$stripped = str_replace($characters, '', $address);
echo $stripped; //  12345 West Palm Rd, 7B Daytona, FL
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [example #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#example-4545) on **`strtr`** function doc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\./', '', $address);
$str = preg_replace('/#/', '', $str);
```

Comment: '.' is a meta character in regex.  Additionally, all the power of regex, and still two calls to it?

Comment: Won't the first wipe the entire `$address`?

Answer (score 1):

`$string = strtr($string, array('.' => '', '#' => ''));`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following php code:

```
$smt="12345 West Palm Rd., #7B Daytona, FL";
$smt=str_replace(".","",$smt);
$smt=str_replace("#","",$smt);
```